# Jquery: get array of widths of td's in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to get an array of the width of all `td`'s in a row.  First I get the array of all the `td`'s:

```
datas = $('.totals').prev().find("tr").last().find("td");
```

Then to test that I am using the `$.map` method correctly, I have it output each element:

```
$.map(datas, function(the_data){console.log(the_data)});
```

The above code returns:

```
<td class="col col-name">18</td>
<td class="col col-1">1</td>
<td class="col col-2">2</td>
<td class="col col-3">0</td>
<td class="col col-4">3</td>
<td class="col col-5">3%</td>
```

I now try to run the `$.map` method to collect the width of all the `td`'s:

```
$.map(datas, function(the_data){the_data.width();});
```

The code above returns:

```
VM4255:1 Uncaught TypeError: the_data.width is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:42
    at Function.map (jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:485)
    at <anonymous>:1:3
```

I have also tried:

```
$.map(datas, function(){$(this).width();});
```

but that just returns an empty array.

How do I get the array of widths?

Comment: the object 'the_data' in your map function is not a jQuery object, have you tried this $(the_data)?

Comment: @ÁngelB. That worked!  If you leave it as an answer i'll mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object 'the_data' in your map function is not a jQuery object, you have to add a jQuery selector to get a jQuery object:

```
$.map(datas, function(the_data){$(the_data).width();});
```

Then you can access to jQuery width() method.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid using `map` altogether if you're simply trying to get an array of widths:

```
var widths = [];
datas = $('.totals').prev().find("tr").last().find("td");

datas.each(function() {             //iterate through each cell
    widths.push($(this).width());   //add its width to the array
});
```

Comment: Why would you not want to use `map`? You're essentially implementing your own version of `map` in the code above.

Comment: It seems that OP isn't clear on how to use map, so I'm providing an alternative that they may be more comfortable with. The syntax for an `each` is about as black-and-white as it gets, and the performance difference is entirely negligible in this use-case. If OP is set on `map`, they can skip my answer and find one they like more.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning anything inside the callback for `$.map`. You need to return the width inside the function like so:

```
$.map(datas, function(){return $(this).width();});
```